Is the electrostatic energy of a continuous charge distribution always positive?
(Griffiths 2.4.3)
The energy of a continuous charge distribution is:
$$
W=\frac{\epsilon_0}{2}\int\limits_{all\ space}{E^2d\tau}
$$
This equation mathematically enforces the fact that the energy of any continuous charge distribution is non-negative.
What I need is a physical clarification of why this is indeed always true. For example, if I make a continuous charge distribution with both positive and negative charges, it seems somewhat counterintuitive that the energy can never be negative.

This question asked before on Physics SE is similar to my question, but I wasn't satisfied with its answer.

Are you not aware that $E^2$ is always nonnegative? Why is this not a satisfactory answer for you? What explanation are you looking for?

Asking for an "intuitive explanation" without clarification is much too vague.

I know that $E^2$ is nonnegative. I can also understand that the mathematical expression confirms that energy is not negative. But, I was looking for a more intuitive physical reason why it cannot be negative.

If you can clarify it a bit more I will be willing to vote to reopen, but in short I imagine it is roughly because the charge density in a small neighborhood around almost any point is the same sign as the charge density at the point. Remember to tick the box to submit for review (in the edit page) when you are ready.
